# In Rails 6, how can I use a route parameter as the controller method name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a reports controller with several actions, one for each kind of report.

I was planning to have them route like this:

/reports/:report_type

I'd like the report_type string fragment to be used as the controller name so that I can have a single route to handle all of them, something like this:

```
  get 'reports/:rpt_type' => "reports#:rpt_type"
```

...that would resolve to this, as an example:

```
  get 'reports/song_performers' => 'reports#song_performers'
```

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. You could handle this in the controller, rather than the routes.rb file:

```rb
# reports_controller.rb
def show
  send(params[:rpt_type])
end

private
def song_performers
  # do stuff
end

def other_type
  # do other stuff
end

# in routes.rb
get 'reports/:rpt_type', to: 'reports#show'
```

Comment: This worked, but I needed to change `params(:rpt_type)` to `params[:rpt_type]` and `get 'reports/:rpt_type' to: 'reports#show'` to `get 'reports/:rpt_type', to: 'reports#show'`. I was even able to remove the separate instance methods and put all the logic in the `show` method. Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't sure if it would be ok for me to edit the answer code but it looks like someone else made the first correction so I figured I'd do the second one.